# Designing and planning a "plugin extendible" application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, plugins

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am planning to create an "extendible" application. That is, to have a main application for\in which I can add ("un-invasive") *plugins* without modify the main application at all. These plugins must interact with the main application accordly to its database\code structure.

**How can I handle this issue in designing and planning my application database structure (primary\foreign keys, ...) and thinking at the application code implementation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you [Rails::Engine](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Engine.html). Nice example of this are [Refinery CMS](https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms) or [Spree](https://github.com/spree/spree) projects.

You can write migrations in engine and copy them to application db/migrate with generator for example.